# Use token card in payment intention stripe

Tags: java, stripe-payments

How can I user token card (Stripe) in `PaymentIntetion`?

I need an example because I don't have an idea.

In `Charge` works, but I don't have idea how to work in `PaymentIntention`:

```
public Charge createCharge(Integer price,String token,String product)throws StripeException {
    Stripe.apiKey = stripeSecret;
    String tokenStripe = "";
    
    

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("amount", price);
    params.put("currency", "eur");
    params.put("source", token);
    params.put( "description"," Payment produto: "+product);


    Charge charge = Charge.create(params);
    
    return charge;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use token in Payment Intent. Payment Intent only supports [`payment_method`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-payment_method) (pm_xxx).

Tokens/Charges API are legacy integration and no longer recommended. I'd recommend using Payment Intent with Payment Element integration. You may refer to the guide here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart